# Django - Displaying video with jwplayer

Tags: django, jwplayer, django-media

I am currently trying to display a video on a website using jwplayer. The view for the page is

```
def video(request):
        return render_to_response('video_player/video.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

And the html template being used contains this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
```

And this in the body:

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "{{ MEDIA }}videos/test.mp4",
        image: "{{ MEDIA }}videos/cute-bunny.jpg"
    });
</script>
```

It doesn't display anything other than 'Loading the player', i think there may be something wrong with me calling the media_root. It is defined as:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Timmy/Documents/GitHub/GroupProject/media'
```

Comment: Do you have a link we can look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` tag in your templates, which you define in settings.py.

Example in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

MEDIA_ROOT, like STATIC_ROOT, is the **directory** that Django uses to upload media files to and serve media files from, not the URL path.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user